# Difference between Kafka and ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic, apache-kafka

I have been working on `Active MQ` for quite some time and familiar with the `Active MQ` architecture.
Recently I have been hearing a lot about `Kafka` as a messaging system.
What advantages does it have over Active MQ and other messaging system? Is it just another Big data buzz word?
Also is `kafka` suitable for zero loss messaging system?

Comment: Funny to be close as opinion-based! These systems have their own purposes and goals to achieve and have their own strengths and weaknesses when compared in different scenarios; how can this be opinion-based? (voted to reopen)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is too broad to discuss but in my opinion the most important factor about `Kafka` over `ActiveMQ` is the `throughput`. From the wiki page

> *Kafka provides an extremely high throughput distributed publish/subscribe messaging system. Additionally, it supports relatively long term persistence of messages to support a wide variety of consumers, partitioning of the message stream across servers and consumers, and functionality for loading data into Apache Hadoop for offline, batch processing.*

**Also is kafka suitable for zero loss messaging system?**

In very brief kafka Guarantees these following :

 1) Messages sent by a producer to a particular topic partition will be appended in the order they are sent. 
2) For a topic with replication factor N, it will tolerate up to N-1 server failures without losing any messages committed to the log.